# case statement between dates in the format of month and year in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert data in `EXPIRATION_DATE` of `PERMIT` table from `ATR_CERT_DATE` of `Facility` table based on conditions below

> IF ATR_CERT_DATE is between 1/1 (m/day) and 7/31(m/day) then
>   EXPIRATION_DATE is 12/31/YY (current year)
>
> IF ATR_CERT_DATE is between 8/1/YY and 12/31/YY then EXPIRATION_DATE
>   is 12/31/YY+1 (Next year)

For Example,

When data in `ATR_CERT_DATE` is like below

```
ATR_CERT_DATE
----
1996-12-30
2001-01-22
```

Expected results in `EXPIRATION_DATE` should be like

```
EXPIRATION_DATE
----
1997-12-31
2001-12-31
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ATR_CERT_DATE
    ,CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(ATR_CERT_DATE)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(ATR_CERT_DATE)) BETWEEN '01-01' AND '07-31'
            THEN cast(datepart(yyyy, ATR_CERT_DATE) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + '12-31'
        WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(ATR_CERT_DATE)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(ATR_CERT_DATE)) BETWEEN '08-01' AND '12-31'
            THEN cast(datepart(yyyy, DATEADD(year, 1, ATR_CERT_DATE)) AS VARCHAR) + + '-' + '12-31'
        ELSE '2'
        END AS Effective_date
FROM facility.[dbo].[UST_ATR_HISTORY]
WHERE ATR_CERT_DATE IN (
        '1996-12-30'
        ,'2001-01-22'
        )
```

This query gives almost the expected result except it is a varchar instead of the needed datetime type. How can I get a DateTime from it instead?

Comment: What are the data types of the columns `ATR_CERT_DATE` and `EXPIRATION_DATE`?

Comment: both are datetime

Comment: Have you tried using [`DATEPART`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)? Give it a go and show us your code if you are having problems.

Comment: SELECT distinct ATR_CERT_DATE,
Case
when CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(ATR_CERT_DATE)) + '-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DAY(ATR_CERT_DATE)) between '01-01' and '07-31'
then cast(datepart(yyyy,ATR_CERT_DATE) as varchar)+'-'+ '12-31'
when CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(ATR_CERT_DATE)) + '-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DAY(ATR_CERT_DATE)) between '08-01' and '12-31'
then  cast(datepart(yyyy,DATEADD(year, 1,ATR_CERT_DATE) )as varchar)+ +'-'+ '12-31'
else '2'
End as Effective_date
from facility.[dbo].[UST_ATR_HISTORY]
where ATR_CERT_DATE in ('1996-12-30','2001-01-22')

Comment: @AndrewMorton .. This query gives expected result. I'm getting results in varchar but Expiration_date is in datetime? Can you help in with this issue?Thanks

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question for you in light of your last comment. Please feel free to change my edit however you want.

Comment: @AndrewMorton. I appreciate it. It worked very well :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`SELECT DISTINCT 
    ATR_CERT_DATE,
    case 
        when month(ATR_CERT_DATE) <= 7 
            then dateadd(yyyy, datediff(yyyy, 0, ATR_CERT_DATE) + 1, -1)
            else dateadd(yyyy, datediff(yyyy, 0, ATR_CERT_DATE) + 2, -1)
    end as Effective_date
FROM facility.[dbo].[UST_ATR_HISTORY]
WHERE ATR_CERT_DATE IN ('1996-12-30','2001-01-22')`

Preferred because we aren't converting from date to string and back again, here we're just staying in date type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

To insert the processed data into the `Permit` table you could use

```
INSERT INTO [Permit] ([ID], [EXPIRATION_DATE])
SELECT [ID],
       [EXPIRATION_DATE] = 
        CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(month, UAH.ATR_CERT_DATE) < 8
                THEN CAST((CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, UAH.ATR_CERT_DATE)) + '-12-31') AS DATETIME)
            ELSE CAST((CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, UAH.ATR_CERT_DATE) + 1) + '-12-31') AS DATETIME)
        END
        FROM [UST_ATR_HISTORY] AS UAH
```

(If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, this could be simplified a bit.)

Sample input:

```
ID          ATR_CERT_DATE
----------- -----------------------
1           1996-12-30 00:00:00.000
77          2001-01-22 00:00:00.000
```

Sample result:

```
ID          EXPIRATION_DATE
----------- -----------------------
1           1997-12-31 00:00:00.000
77          2001-12-31 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to cast the varchar data you're already getting back into datetime.  You'd wrap your query in an outer query that just does the conversion:

```
SELECT CAST(a.EXPIRATION_DATE as datetime) as EXPIRATION_DATE
FROM
    (
    [Your existing query]
    ) as a
```

This doesn't address the *why* of your problem, but it should give your the results you want.